# Will reputation not lost on downvotes because of lower rep limit be lost later after gains?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

Suppose somebody asks a [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/377216/can-i-go-out-in-year-10-in-high-school-and-go-to-college) that is unrelated to the site, and receives multiple downvotes. However, the asker still has a reputation of 1. Downvotes will not take away the reputation, as reputation can never be [negative](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down). However, if they ask another question that is well-received, will they lose the amount of reputation they were supposed to lose for the original [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/377216/can-i-go-out-in-year-10-in-high-school-and-go-to-college)? Or will the original question not have any effect?

Comment: As you've already stated, reputation cannot be negative.

Comment: @Servy What I mean is will the lost reputation from the first question be deducted by the well-received second question?

Comment: The reputation would have to be negative for that to happen.  As you have said, reputation can't be negative.

Comment: @Servy no; the second question gets lots of reputation. Will the first question's deducted reputation affect the reputation gained from the second?

Comment: _"No user’s reputation may drop below one point; if an action would cause a user’s reputation to drop below one point, that user only loses enough reputation to drop to one point, and the remaining penalty or loss is waived."_

Comment: @Emereal For that to happen *the reputation would have to become negative*. That's what it would mean.  If getting a downvote would mean that a latter upvote would still leave you below 1 *then your rep has been negative*.

Answer (score 5):

> will they lose the amount of reputation they were supposed to lose for the original question?

No.

> Or will the original question not have any effect?

It still might, if more downvotes come in.

---

You can think of it as a stream of events, each event having a corresponding result:

```
Q1 downvoted - rep is 1 
Q1 downvoted - rep is 1 
Q2 upvoted - rep is 6
Q1 downvoted - rep is 4
```